# Visual Studio/LINQ syntax with a database field called 'date'

Tags: linq, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am building a new VB.net MVC5 front-end for an existing database.  I am constructing the LINQ queries to interrogate the DB through EF6.

One of the tables has a field called 'date' - when I try and construct the LINQ query in VS2013 the UI refuses to recognise the field 'date' as being from the table:

```
 Dim a = From e In db.events
 Select New Models.Tasks With {.TaskID=enq, .Title=task_name, .StartDate=Date}
```

In VS2013 the final curly bracket is underlined (". expected") - the UI not recognising 'Date' as a field in db.events

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Try `@Date` instead of `Date` in C#, or `[Date]` in VB.NET

Comment: Shouldn't that be `e.enq`, `e.task_name`, `e.Date`? Maybe I'm just not up on VB and LINQ...

Comment: I hadn't noticed yet this is VB.NET, comment updated.

Comment: Yes of course - Jon's solution works perfectly - if you make this an answer I'll tick it.  I couldn't get Stijn's to work though.